# Integrating lync 2010 to web application

Tags: lync, lync-2010, lync-server-2010, lync-client-sdk, lync-2013

I am trying to integrate office communicator  Lync 2010 into the web application, is this possible with UCWA (http://ucwa.lync.com/) services  if not how can achieve this ??

Any response is appreciated.

Comment: What part of Lync are you intending to make use of in the web application?  It should be noted that the deploy location would need to be on Lync Server 2013 to utilize UCWA.

Comment: I am trying to integrate Lync phone feature into a web application.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't integrate voice or video using UCWA (though I expect that to change soon). With UCWA, you can only access IM and Presence. UCWA is the best way to integrate lync into a web application that can't use Silverlight. And, as ShelbyZ says, you need Lync 2013 to use UCWA.

If you can put Silverlight on the web page, you can add all sorts of controls onto the page. Have a look at this: http://thoughtstuff.co.uk/2012/05/microsoft-lyncs-development-secret-its-easy/ It's all 2010 as well (as I haven't had a chance to update it yet!)